# Convert json to list in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a dynamic data from json, then I want to change it to a list variable, so i can be called that variable by the getSuggestions function.
Here is the code :

````
static List<String> people = new List<String>();

  void getUsers() async {
    try {
      final response =
          await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      var resbody = json.decode(response.body);
      var data = json.encode(resbody[0]);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          people = data;
        });
      } else {
        print("Error getting users.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error getting users.");
    }
  }

  static List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    List<String> matches = List();
    matches.addAll(people);

    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
  }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### update 1:

try it with

```dart
resbody.map((entry) => (entry['name'])).toList();
```

#### old

could you provide more information?. 
F.e. how does the json look like? Structure etc.

In most cases, json.decode already translates json arrays to flutter Lists. 
Lets say your response has the following structure:

```
{
  "date": "2019-07-18T06:14:36.276Z",
  "body": [
    {
      "amounts": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
      ],
      "name": "string",
    }
  ]
}
```

I would then suggest to create a class Data:

```dart
class Data {
  const Data({this.date, this.body});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Data(
      date: parsedJson['date'] ,
      body: Body.fromJson(parsedJson['body'],
    );
  }

  final String date;
  final Body body;
}
```

and a class Body

```dart
class Body {
  const Body({this.date, this.body});
  factory Body.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Body(
      amounts: parsedJson['amounts'],
      name: parsedJson['name'] ,
    );
  }

  final List<int> amounts;
  final String name;
}
```

Then `data = Data.fromJson(resbody);` should return the Data class. And `data.body.amounts` should return the list.

Comment: this is example from my json, i will take field name :
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: resbody.map((entry) => (entry['name'])).toList();
thats work... great !! thank you very much...